# print only those variable which satisfy condition in waiver file

Tags: unix, tcl, tclsh

i want to print certain vdd and ground in waiver file(fh) which satisfy the condition and print in waiver file.

```
*set matrix_waiver($pwr_name,$gnd_name) 1
if { [info exists matrix_waiver] } {
      foreach power $pwr_name {
          if { [info exists matrix_waiver($power) ] } {
              lappend matrix_waiver $fh_waiver
          }
      }
      foreach ground $gnd_name {
          if { [info exists matrix_waiver($ground) ] } {
              lappend matrix_waiver $fh_waiver
          }
      }
  }*
```

am not getting desired output..whats the error in above code?

Comment: sample data missing

Comment: Sample input and expected output are missing.

Comment: Please supply more details in your question.  Where are the variables of the matrix_waiver array set?  Your first line shows the array set for a "$pwr_name,$gnd_name" but the info exist commands later use variable names with only $pwr_name or $gnd_name, not both of them joined with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using a variable (`matrix_waiver`) as both a simple variable and an associative array. That's not going to work (well, not unless the variable is `unset` between, which I don't think you want to do). The two are fundamentally different in Tcl (they're two of the major types of variable; the third one is a link, which is used to implement `global` and `upvar` and you can usually ignore that).

If the actual data (which you don't show us) is a simple variable, which still might include complex structures such as lists and dictionaries within it, then you're going to have to use `lindex` and `lset` and `lappend` and so on to work with it.

If the actual data is an associative array, you'll need to supply the correct element names when doing `lappend` and so on.